# Sending many requests from Node.js to an API causes error

Tags: javascript, node.js, facebook, api, node-request

I have more than 2000 user in my database , when I try to broadcast a message to all users, it barely sends about 200 request then my server stops and I get an error as below :

```
{ Error: connect ETIMEDOUT 31.13.88.4:443
at Object.exports._errnoException (util.js:1026:11)
at exports._exceptionWithHostPort (util.js:1049:20)
at TCPConnectWrap.afterConnect [as oncomplete] (net.js:1090:14)
code: 'ETIMEDOUT',
errno: 'ETIMEDOUT',
syscall: 'connect,
address: '31.13.88.4',
port: 443 }
```

*Sometimes* I get another error that says :

```
Error!: Error: socket hang up
```

This is my request :

```
function callSendAPI(messageData) {
  request({
    uri: 'https://graph.facebook.com/v2.6/me/messages',
    qs: { access_token: '#####' },
    method: 'POST',
    json: messageData

  }, function (error, response, body) {
    if (!error && response.statusCode == 200) {
      var recipientId = body.recipient_id;
      var messageId = body.message_id;

      if (messageId) {
        console.log("Successfully sent message with id %s to recipient %s", 
          messageId, recipientId);
      } else {
      console.log("Successfully called Send API for recipient %s", 
        recipientId);
      }
    } else {
      console.error("Failed calling Send API");
      console.log(error)
    }
  });  
}
```

**I have tried**

`setTimeout` to make the the API calling wait for a while:

```
 setTimeout(function(){callSendAPI(data)},200);
```

Can anyone help if he/she faced a similar error ?

**EDITED**

I'm using Messenger Platform which support high rate of calls to the Send API and it is not limited with 200 calls .

Comment: @mplungjan I did , but i have not catch an answer related to the http.request

Comment: q=ETIMEDOUT+node.js+POST+facebook

Comment: Are you making 2000 concurrent requests to graph.facebook.com and wondering why this fails? :)

Comment: @JeremyThille  Sorry ! What is the problem with making 2000 request ? i'm not directly  using the graph.API .. i'm using the Messenger API through Graphs which has no limits .

Comment: Oh, in that case that's different, you're right if it's the messenger API.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may be hitting Facebook API limits. To throttle the requests you should send every request after some interval from the previous one. You didn't include where you're iterating over all users but I suspect that you maybe do it in a loop and if you use `setTimeout` to delay every request with flat 200ms delay then you have all requests done at the same time like you did before - just 200ms later.

What you can do is:

1. You can use setTimeout and add variable delay for every request (not recommended)
2. You can use Async module's `series` or `parallelLimit` (using callbacks)
3. You can use Bluebird's `Promise.mapSeries` or `Promise.map` with `concurrency` limit (using promises)

The 1 is not recommended because it will still be fire-and-forget (unless you add more complexity to that) and you still risk that you have too much concurrency and go over limit because you only control when the requests start, not how many of outstanding requests are there.

The 2 and 3 are mostly the same but differ by using callbacks or promises. In your example you're using callbacks but your `callSendAPI` doesn't take its own callback which it should if you want option 2 to work - or, alternatively, it should return a promise if you want option 3 to work.

For more info see the docs:

- https://caolan.github.io/async/docs.html#parallelLimit
- https://caolan.github.io/async/docs.html#series
- http://bluebirdjs.com/docs/api/promise.map.html
- http://bluebirdjs.com/docs/api/promise.mapseries.html

Of course there are more ways to do it but those are the most straightforward.

Ideally, if you want to fully utilize the 200 requests per hour limit then you should queue the requests yourself and make the requests at certain intervals that correspond to that limit. Sometimes if you didn't do a lot of requests in an hour then you won't need delays, sometime you will. What you should really do here is to queue all requests centrally and empty the queue at intervals corresponding to the already used up portion to the limit which you should track yourself - but that can be tricky.

Comment: Thanks for your comment ,Messenger Platform supports a high rate of calls to the Send API it does not has a limit 
https://developers.facebook.com/docs/messenger-platform/send-api-reference

I do not directly call the graph API , i call messenger API and it has no limit for api calling

Answer (score -1):

It sounds like you are hitting a rate limit.

From the [Facebook documentation](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/advanced/rate-limiting):

> Your app can make 200 calls per hour per user in aggregate.

You can check the [dashboard](https://developers.facebook.com/apps/) to see if you are hitting the rate limiting in these cases.

Comment: Thanks for your comment ,Messenger Platform supports a high rate of calls to the Send API it does not has a limit 
https://developers.facebook.com/docs/messenger-platform/send-api-reference